# How to incorporate imtool3D in axes of personal GUI, using GUIDE - MatLab

Tags: user-interface, matlab-guide

**I am trying to incorporate the imtool3D function into my personal GUI. But if i click on the pushbutton, with this code below it:**

```
axes(handles.axes1);

imtool3D([],[],handles.axes1);
```

**MatLab gives an error:**

```
Error using uipanel
While setting the 'Parent' property of Panel:
Axes cannot be a parent.

Error in imtool3D (line 251)
            tool.handles.Panels.Large   =   uipanel(tool.handles.fig,'Position',position,'Title','','Tag','imtool3D');
            set(tool.handles.Panels.Large,'Units','Pixels'); pos=get(tool.handles.Panels.Large,'Position');
            set(tool.handles.Panels.Large,'Units','normalized');

Error in image_registration>pushbutton3_Callback (line 106)
imtool3D([],[],handles.axes1);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in image_registration (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)image_registration('pushbutton3_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Answer (score 0):

imtool3D needs to be put into a panel or a figure. It cannot be put into an axis.